Helm: List recent chart upgrades
Given a kubernetes cluster with many helm charts in different namespaces, how can I use helm to query the list of the last recently "touched" charts?
By "touched" I mean either installed (via helm install) or upgraded (via helm upgrade).
Something like: helm ls --all --sort-by updated.
I am also fine with a solution that uses kubectl directly.

The brute force way:
helm ls --max 99999 -A -o json | jq -r '.[] | "\(.updated)\t\(.name)"' | sort | tail | column -t


-A for all namespaces
--max 99999 to "disable" paging (there's no better way as of 2024-09-24)
jq to filter out on the "updated" field

Note that a sample json entry looks like the following:
{
  "name": "hoth-cb7f8a327",
  "namespace": "default",
  "revision": "2",
  "updated": "2024-06-14 15:02:16.775174131 +0000 UTC",
  "status": "deployed",
  "chart": "hoth-0.1.0",
  "app_version": "1.0.0"
}

Sample output of the aforementioned command:
2024-09-24  10:56:15.655674586  +0000  UTC  geonosis
2024-09-24  10:56:15.731630075  +0000  UTC  coruscant
2024-09-24  11:01:35.156973247  +0000  UTC  endor
2024-09-24  11:02:30.314014351  +0000  UTC  hoth

